# What does it mean to have a perl hash{}{}

Tags: perl, hash

My professor has some syntax on a slide that I do not understand.

In perl there is:

```
$hash{$string}{$anotherString}++;
```

What does this syntax mean? If it were:

```
$hash{$string}{$int}++;
```

Would it be increment the value?
When I print using

```
while( my( $key, $value ) = each %hash ){print "$key: $value\n";}
```

My output is 
    "key": HASH(0xbe0200)

Comment: If `$hash{$string}{$anotherString}` is an integer, then `$hash{$string}{$anotherString}++` increments it.  What's the question?

Comment: Your output is reasonable.  `$hash{$string}` is a hash.  It's value at the index `$anotherString` is an integer, and this line of code is incrementing it.

Comment: So this is just another way of writing the key value pair?

Comment: Perhaps the code would be clearer if written `$hash_of_hash{$string}{$another_string}`.  This is explained fairly well in the documentation: `perldoc perllol`

Comment: Thanks this has me going on the right path now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a two-dimensional hash, a hash of hashes. It is easy to keep track of structures in Perl once you realize that any single value is in fact a scalar. In the case of multidimensional structures, the scalar value is a reference. For example:

```
my %outer = ( "foo" => { "bar" => 1 } );
```

The inner part `{ "bar" => 1 }` is a hash reference. The use of `{ }` in assignment denotes an anonymous hash. This is similar to:

```
my %inner = ( "bar" => 1 );
my %outer = ( "foo" => \%inner );
```

Now when you want to reference a value in `%inner`, you use the first key to access the hash reference, and the second key to access the value in `%inner`:

```
print $outer{"foo"}{"bar"};  # prints 1
```

And when you use the [increment operator `++`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) on a value, it is incremented:

```
$outer{"foo"}{"bar"}++;      # the value is now 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$hash{string1}{string2}
```

is a shorter equivalent of

```
$hash{string1}->{string2}
```

i.e. it returns a value from a hash of hashes.

By applying the `++` operator, the value in the inner hash is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

> My output is "key": HASH(0xbe0200)

That strange output means that what you are trying to print is actually a *hash reference*:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;  #allows you to use say(), which is equivalent to print() 
            #plus a newline at the end

my $href = {
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
};

say $href;

--output:--
HASH(0x100826698)
```

Or,

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
);

say \%hash;

--output:--
HASH(0x1008270a0)
```

The `\` operator gets the *reference* for the thing on its right hand side.

The easiest way to print the actual hash is using Data::Dumper, which is something you can and will use all the time:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $href = {
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
};


say Dumper($href);

$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

Like `use warnings;`, I consider `use Data::Dumper;` mandatory for every program.

So, when you see strange output, like `HASH(0xbe0200)`, use Data::Dumper on the value:

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => { hello => 2, goodbye => 3},
);

while( my( $key, $value ) = each %hash ){
    say $key;
    say Dumper($value);
    say '-' x 10;
}

--output:--
a
$VAR1 = 1;

----------
b
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => 2,
          'goodbye' => 3
        };

----------
```

Or, alternatively just use Data::Dumper on the whole structure:

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => { hello => 2, goodbye => 3},
);


say Dumper(\%hash);

--output:--
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => {
                   'hello' => 2,
                   'goodbye' => 3
                 }
        };
```

Note that Dumper() is used to show the contents of a hash reference(or any other reference), so if your variable is not a reference, e.g. `%hash`, then you must turn it into a reference using the `\` operator, e.g. `\%hash`.

Now, if you have this hash:

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => { hello => 2, goodbye => 3},
);
```

...to retrieve the value corresponding to 'goodbye', you can write:

```
say $hash{b}{goodbye};  #=>3
```

`$hash{b}` returns the hash (reference) `{ hello => 2, goodbye => 3}`, and you can retrieve values from that hash by using the subscripts `{hello}` or `{goodbye}`.

Alternatively, you can write this:

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => { hello => 2, goodbye => 3},
);

my $string = 'b';
my $anotherString = 'goodbye';

say $hash{$string}{$anotherString};  #=>3
```

And to increment the value 3 in the hash, you can write:

```
my $result = $hash{$string}{$anotherString}++;
say $result;  #=>3
say $hash{$string}{$anotherString};  #=>4
```

The `postfix ++` operator actually increments the value *after* the current operation, so $result is 3, then the value in the hash is incremented to 4, something like this:

```
my $temp = $hash{$string}{$anotherString};
$hash{$string}{$anotherString} = $hash{$string}{$anotherString} + 1;
my $result = $temp;
```

If you want the increment to happen *before* the current operation, then you can use the `prefix ++` operator:

```
my $result = ++$hash{$string}{$anotherString};
say $result;  #=>4
say $hash{$string}{$anotherString}; #=>4
```

Finally, if the value at `$hash{$string}{$anotherString}` is not a number, e.g. 'green', you will get something strange:

```
my %hash = (
    a => 1,
    b => { hello => 2, goodbye => 'green'},
);

my $string = 'b';
my $anotherString = 'goodbye';

my $result = $hash{$string}{$anotherString}++;
say $hash{$string}{$anotherString};

--output:--
greeo
```

perl has a notion that the string that comes after the string 'green' is the string 'greeo' because the letter 'o' comes after the letter 'n' in the alphabet.  And if the string you incremented were 'greez' the output would be:

```
  greez  original
  grefa  output
```

The next letter after 'z' is to start over with 'a', but just like when you increment 9 by 1 and get 10, the increment for 'z' carries over to the column on the left, incrementing that letter by 1, producing the 'f'. Ha!